# Why won't Application Insights data show in my dashboard when reported from a Background Task?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've got MS App Insights data being logged from a Background Task when it runs. However, though I receive no exceptions from AI when debugging the code, nothing is showing in my dashboard as I would expect. All other telemetry from the same session (in main app, not Background Task) logs just fine.

I'm attempting this on Windows 10 Mobile with AI pkg v1.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the key was utilizing the new `PersistenceChannel` as the Channel for my Telemetry like so:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = new PersistenceChannel();
```

then in my bg task:

```
var c = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = <my app insights key> };
c.TrackEvent(evt);
c.Flush();
```

The [documentation for `PersistenceChannel`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/#persistence-channel) shows how it does what AI previously did automatically: cache results to local storage until they're able to be sent to the AI service.

This enabled my background task to fire off and cache its analytics until such time that the user launched the app (and therefore the AI objects got access to the backend service) or the bg task had enough time & muscle to do it itself.

Comment: PersistenceChannel isn't supported anymore and doesn't work. Flushing doesn't send the AI data away so quick. May lag up to 30 minutes before anything actually shows up in the AI portal.

Comment: Not really surprising considering the whole thing is no longer valid for apps anyway ;) Supposed to use HockeyApp now.

Comment: Why do you say that, as I understand we're supposed to use the AppInsights SDK to log telemetry, traces, events, exceptions - whatever. I haven't read anywhere that a "HockeyApp" is gonna replace AI. Please enlighten a confused soul. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to .flush() the TelemetryClient periodically, or before your Background Task exits.